# Rename result from aggregate function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Would someone please help me to figure out how I can rename these highlighted items?
"Count" should be (Most popular Item") and "sum" should be "most popular Item"

[image]

Here is my code

```html
most_popular_item = Heroes_file.groupby(["Item ID", "Item Name","Price"]).agg({"Price": ['count','sum']})
```

Comment: `df["most popular item"] = ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

To rename your pandas columns you can use [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html).

Like this,

```
most_popular_item.columns = most_popular_item.columns.droplevel(0)
```

will remove 'Price' by removing the outer most level.

Then you can simply use rename

```
most_popular_item.rename({'count': 'not_count', 'sum': 'not_sum'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
```